# parsing the csv file with multiline fields in pyspark

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Facing an issue while reading the test2.csv file in pyspark.

Test file `test1.csv`

```
a1^b1^c1^d1^e1
a2^"this is having 
multiline data1
multiline data2"^c2^d2^e2
a3^b3^c3^d3^e3
a4^b4^c4^d4^e4
```

Test file `test2.csv`

```
a1^b1^c1^d1^e1
a2^this is having 
multiline data1
multiline data2^c2^d2^e2
a3^b3^c3^d3^e3
a4^b4^c4^d4^e4
```

Below is the Code

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("A", StringType()),
    StructField("B", StringType()),
    StructField("C", StringType()),
    StructField("D", StringType()),    
    StructField("E", StringType())
])
```

Creating the dataframe for the above 2 csv files.

`df1=spark.read.csv("s3_path/test1.csv",schema=schema,inferSchema=True,multiLine=True,sep='^')
    df1.show(10,False)
    print ('df1.count() is: ', df1.count())`

```
Below is the output when I read the test1.csv file
+---+-----------------------------------------------+---+---+---+
|A  |B                                              |C  |D  |E  |
+---+-----------------------------------------------+---+---+---+
|a1 |b1                                             |c1 |d1 |e1 |
|a2 |this is having 
multiline data1
multiline data2|c2 |d2 |e2 |
|a3 |b3                                             |c3 |d3 |e3 |
|a4 |b4                                             |c4 |d4 |e4 |
+---+-----------------------------------------------+---+---+---+

df1.count() is: 4



df2 = spark.read.csv("s3_path/test2.csv",schema=schema,inferSchema=True,multiLine=True,sep='^')
df2.show(10,False)
print ('df2.count() is: ', df2.count())


Below is the output when I read the test2.csv file
+---------------+---------------+----+----+----+
|A              |B              |C   |D   |E   |
+---------------+---------------+----+----+----+
|a1             |b1             |c1  |d1  |e1  |
|a2             |this is having |null|null|null|
|multiline data1|null           |null|null|null|
|multiline data2|c2             |d2  |e2  |null|
|a3             |b3             |c3  |d3  |e3  |
|a4             |b4             |c4  |d4  |e4  |
+---------------+---------------+----+----+----+

df2.count() is: 6
```

Source Files:
If we see the difference in source files. test1.csv has `"` at the beginning and end of the multiline data. But test2.csv doesnt have that.

Issue Description: Column B, 2nd row has multiline data. If we see the output of the df2, it has 6 records, here spark is reading it as new record which is `not correct`.
The output of the df1 has 4 records, the multiline data in column B 2nd row is treated as one string which is `correct`.

Question : Can someone help to fix the code to read the test2.csv file as well correctly.

Comment: I guess column **qualifier** (single or double quotes) is made necessary for a csv file for the purpose of escaping the **delimeter** itself. But you can give a try for the "quote" option in the `read.csv` method.

Comment: @PrakashS  `options quote` parameter is not solving the purpose here, It works like below.  
Test file: 
`a1^b1^c1^d1^e1
a2^$its a single line ^data$^c2^d2^e2
a3^b3^c3^d3^e3
a4^b4^c4^d4^e4`
       
`spark.read.option('quote','$').option("multiLine","true").option("inferSchema", "true").schema(schema).option("sep","^").option("header", "false").csv("s3://aria-preprod.snowflake.stg/pca/volatility/spark_issue/testy.csv").show(10,False)`

Comment: Output:
`
+---+---------------------+---+---+---+
|A  |B                    |C  |D  |E  |
+---+---------------------+---+---+---+
|a1 |b1                   |c1 |d1 |e1 |
|a2 |its a single line ^data|c2 |d2 |e2 |
|a3 |b3                   |c3 |d3 |e3 |
|a4 |b4                   |c4 |d4 |e4 |
+---+---------------------+---+---+---+
`